# How to smooth rough surface scanned with 3D scanner?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Newbies here need help. I scanned a model with 3D scanner, but the surface is rough and have a lot of bumpy areas and I would like to smooth them. I tried Decimate, Auto Smooth, Smooth, but it's not working. Appreciate if someone can guide me.

[image]

Comment: If you can post the .blend file, someone might be interested enough to give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

You could try 3 different smooth modifiers:

[image]

Corrective Smooth seems to be appropriate here. It works a bit weird, since you need to lower the scale in order for it to have an effect:

You can apply the modifier to the mesh by hitting  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>  while hovering the mouse over the modifier in the UI once you are happy with the result.

[image]